# How can I show a list of terms from a specific vocabulary that are not assigned to the current node

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I need to create a view of terms from a specific vocabulary for a specific node, where the view will contain only those terms that are *not* assigned to that node.

I've tried various methods within Views without luck. The closest I got was to use aggregation so I could identify terms with a zero node count. I had hoped that by using the NID as a contextual filter then the view would only count based on the current node. That's not how it worked out.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

David

Comment: Seems that you want [this feature](https://drupal.org/node/1349922) - it was closed (fixed) by mistake of stupid script. I fixed it's entry, but closed (can't fix) is not something that can make you happy, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like it should be easy but ... :(

Comment: ... but that's not how SQL queries work, and Views are heavily SQL based. There is no general way, but it is relatively easy in custom module. See here https://www.google.pl/search?q=sql+anti-join for a lot of interesting texts about that problem.